# Karma unit test setup trying to load a css which is not present

Tags: css, karma-runner

I have a project setup where i am using 
Angular2 + Typescript
Webpack for bundling
Karma + Jamine

## Problem statement

I have a scss file where i am having a import at the top
Which is @import "variables.global";

While Karma server is executing my testcase it is trying to load that file which it can't find and throws 404 error

I have above import on many scss file and due to same many of my test cases are failing.

My question is that why Karma is trying to load a css @import as a normal javascript module.

It is making a call like 
http://localhost:9876/variables.global

Above seems wrong to me because

here is my karma config if needed

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: "",
        frameworks: [
            'jasmine',
            'karma-typescript'
        ],
        reporters: [
            "progress",
            "karma-typescript",
            "html"
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.ts': [
                'karma-typescript'
            ]
            ,'app/*.*scss': ['scss']
            ,'app/**/*.*scss': ['scss']
        },
        files: [
            {
                pattern: 'test/base.ts'
            },
            {
                pattern: 'app/**/*.ts'
            },
            {
                pattern: 'test/*.spec.ts'
            },
            {
                pattern: "./app/i18n/*.json",
                watched: true,
                served: true,
                included: false
            },
            { pattern: 'app/*.*scss', watched: true,  included: true, served: true },        
            { pattern: 'app/main.ts', watched: false,  included: false, served: false },        
        ],
        karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            exclude: ["broken"],
            tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
            coverageOptions: {
                instrumentation: true                
            },
            bundlerOptions: {
                entrypoints: /base\.ts|\.spec\.ts$/,
                transforms: [
                    require('karma-typescript-es6-transform')({
                        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
                        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
                        plugins: [
                            ["transform-runtime", {
                                regenerator: true,
                                polyfill: true
                            }]
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            }
        },
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        browsers: [
            'Chrome'
        ]
    });
};
```

## Recent update

if i change @import "_variables.global.scss"; 
to
@import "base/app/_variables.global.css";
all my test cases qualifies.

But i can't do that because i am doing bundling using Webpack and it will give more errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after huge struggle i have identified the solution

i have written the script to update the path in memory

Here are my bundlerOptions. See carefully the custom transformer i am having.
The way to indetify scss file might not be best which can be replaced by a regex easily.

```
            bundlerOptions: {
            entrypoints: /base\.ts|\.spec\.ts$/,
            resolve: {
                extensions: [".js", ".json"],
                directories: ["node_modules"]
            },
            transforms: [
                require('karma-typescript-es6-transform')({
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
                    plugins: [
                        ["transform-runtime", {
                            regenerator: true,
                            polyfill: true
                        }]
                    ]
                }),
                /**
                 * Custom transformer to resolved the issue related
                 * to importing the css from server.
                 */
                function(context, callback) {
                    if(context.module.indexOf('.scss') !== -1) {
                        context.source = context.source.replace(
                            '@import "variables.global";',
                            '@import "/base/app/_variables.global.css"'
                        );
                        return callback(undefined, true);
                    }
                    return callback(undefined, false);
                }
            ]
        }
```